# How to control order of elements in XML created with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm generating an XML document with PHP and the elements have to be in a specific order. Most of them work fine, with the exception of three. The child elements looks like this:

```
  <p>
    <co>ABC</co>
    <nbr>123456</nbr>
    <name>short product description</name>
    <desc>long product description</desc>
    <kw>searchable keywords</kw>
    <i-std>relative/path/to/image</i-std>
    <i-lg>relative/path/to/large/image</i-lg>
    <i-thmb>relative/path/to/thumbnail</i-thmb>
    <mfg>manufacturer</mfg>
    <a-pckCont>package contents</a-pckCont>
</p>
```

The code I'm using works fine, but the three image elements are out of order, which makes the content processor that consumes them choke. What I've tried most lately is this:

```
$newStd = 0;
foreach ($items as $row => $innerArray) {
    $p = $domTree->createElement('p');
    $xmlRoot->appendChild($p);
    foreach ($innerArray as $innerRow => $value) {
        if ($innerRow != 'key') {
            if ($value != '') {
                echo $innerRow . ' : ' . $value . '<br />';
                if ($innerRow == 'i-std') {
                    $newStd = $domTree->createElement($innerRow, htmlspecialchars($value));
                } else {
                    $p->appendChild($domTree->createElement($innerRow, htmlspecialchars($value)));
                }
            }
        }
        if ($newStd != 0) {
            $thmb = $p->getElementsByTagName('i-thmb')->item(0);
            $p->insertBefore($newStd, $thmb);
        }
    }
}
```

My thought was to have it write out all child elements before I have it write the  element in using InsertBefore to ensure it appears before the i-thmb element, but it didn't make a difference. No matter what I do, the output I get has them in the order i-thmb, i-std, i-lg. All other elements appear in the proper order, after rearranging some of the variables in the arrays used to build the XML document. I haven't attempted to control the i-lg element yet, since i-std isn't working.

Ultimately, this will be used to combine to XML documents together, but in testing to be sure the XML processor wasn't going to choke, I found the fundamental issue is that the order of elements largely determines if it will work or not (the system I'm working with is undocumented and support is poor, to say the least).

Edit to add: echoing as I do in the inner foreach loop shows them in the correct order but they're out of order in the output file.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of `$items`? It's a bit difficult to imagine what you are trying to achieve without a sample of the actual data you are working with.

Comment: $items are the elements contained within the <p> blocks - the XML at the top is an example. The document I'm working with is pretty basic - all the <p> elements are children of <eContent>. I'm reading the original document in to a nested array - the outer array contains arrays made up of the data contained within each <p>. At the moment, literally all I'm doing is rewriting an existing XML document, as I can't go any further until I can control the order of the child elements of <p> in the output file.

Comment: Can you try a couple of changes, update the test to `if ($newStd instanceof DOMElement) {` as you will get a Notice due to types, also move `$newStd = 0;` inside the inner `foreach()` otherwise it keeps on adding the item in each loop.

Comment: @NigelRen - If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Worked brilliantly, although I realized PHP doesn't seem well-suited to what I'm working on, so I'm going to try C# instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a couple of changes would make the code more robust (I've added comments to the code for specifics).  This mainly involves checking of data types and resetting the replacement field in each loop...

```
foreach ($items as $row => $innerArray) {
    $p = $domTree->createElement('p');
    $xmlRoot->appendChild($p);
    foreach ($innerArray as $innerRow => $value) {
        $newStd = 0;    // Make sure this is set each time
        if ($innerRow != 'key') {
            if ($value != '') {
                echo $innerRow . ' : ' . $value . '<br />';
                if ($innerRow == 'i-std') {
                    $newStd = $domTree->createElement($innerRow, htmlspecialchars($value));
                } else {
                    $p->appendChild($domTree->createElement($innerRow, htmlspecialchars($value)));
                }
            }
        }
        // Check if a replacement element, checking type of element
        if ($newStd instanceof DOMElement) {
            $thmb = $p->getElementsByTagName('i-thmb')->item(0);
            $p->insertBefore($newStd, $thmb);
        }
    }
}
```